# How to validate two object use devexpress expression?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have 2 class,and i need to validate fields together,how can i validate then together?

Now i can only validate one class,how can i validate age and height together?

I have tryed use dynamic object,the dynamic object include ClassA fields and ClassB fields,but it doesn't work...

Thanks...

```cs
public class ClassA
{
    public string Age { get; set; } = "11";
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string Height { get; set; } = "30";
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //I need validate age and height together,what should i do?
        string expression = "[Age] <= 15 & [Height] <= 20";

        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        ClassB b = new ClassB();

        var aProps = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(a);
        var func = CompileCriteria(aProps, expression);

        //var res = func.Invoke(a);
    }

    private static Func<object, object> CompileCriteria(
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties, string criteria)
    {
        if (properties == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("properties");
        }
        if (criteria == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("criteria");
        }

        OperandValue[] ov;

        CriteriaOperator expression = CriteriaOperator.Parse(criteria, out ov);
        var descriptor = new CriteriaCompiledContextDescriptorDescripted(properties);

        return CriteriaCompiler.ToUntypedDelegate(expression, descriptor, null);
    }
}
```